# Scanning Java package for annotations

Tags: java, recursion, annotations

I want to implement logic that will recursively scan for annotated classes.  I can scan the package structure without issue:

```
Stack<Package> stack = new Stack<Package>();
stack.push(Package.getPackage(ROOT_PACKAGE));
while(!stack.isEmpty()) {
    Package temp = stack.pop();             
    annotatedClasses.addAll(getAnnotatedClasses(temp));         
    for(Package p : temp.getPackages()) {
        stack.push(p);
    }
}
```

Where I've come unstuck is that I can't seem to find a way to implement this method:

```
public List<Class> getAnnotatedClasses(Package p);
```

Given a Package object is there a way to get all Classes within it?

Comment: I would recommend getting [someone else](http://code.google.com/p/reflections/) to do the legwork for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You can scan for the classes in the package using reflection [Using Reflections to get all classes of package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520328/can-you-find-all-classes-in-a-package-using-reflection) and then recursively go inside all the classes to find the annotations.